# pd.DataFrame.from_dict() won't work for column-wise Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to create into a Dataframe with a single row. The dictionary keys should be the columns and the dictionary values should be all the single row items. For example my dictionary looks as such:

```
{'gross_margin': 92.10000000000001, 'ebitda_margin': 52.8, 'net_margin': 48.199999999999996}
```

I want the Dataframe to look like this:

```
      gross_margin ebitda_margin net_margin
0      92.10000001          52.8   48.19999
```

I have tried to use pd.DataFrame.from_dict() but it doesn't seem to work. This is my attempt:

```
pd_output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='columns')
```

However I get the following error which doesn't make sense as on the documentation doesn't even provide index as an option:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `pd.json_normalize({'gross_margin': 92.10000000000001, 'ebitda_margin': 52.8, 'net_margin': 48.199999999999996})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the values of your `dict` to `lists`

```
dictionary = {'gross_margin': 92.10000000000001, 'ebitda_margin': 52.8, 'net_margin': 48.199999999999996}
dictionary = {k:[v] for k,v in dictionary.items()}
pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

```
   gross_margin  ebitda_margin  net_margin
0          92.1           52.8        48.2
```